# Serilog is empty (.NET 6)

Tags: vb.net, .net-6.0, serilog

I use this code template

```
Dim LoggerConfiguration = New LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.
    Configuration(builder.Build()).
    Enrich.FromLogContext()

Dim AspNetHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().
    ConfigureServices(Sub(X, Y)
                          ConfigureDI(X, Y)
                      End Sub).
    UseSerilog().
    Build()

Log.Logger = LoggerConfiguration.CreateLogger()
Log.Logger.Information("start")
LoggerConfiguration.WriteTo.File("test.txt").WriteTo.Console()
Log.CloseAndFlush()
```

And this config

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
```

Serilog is creating in correct place with correct name, but text not writing, file always empty and has zero length.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to create your logger *after* you're done configuring it:

```
LoggerConfiguration.WriteTo.File("test.txt").WriteTo.Console()
Log.Logger = LoggerConfiguration.CreateLogger()
```

Also, only do this when you exit, so after your host is done running:

```
Log.CloseAndFlush()
```